# Set textview and 2 buttons in a android layout

Tags: android, layout, button, textview

Im trying to set one textview aligned on the left and two bottons aligned on the right as in the image. I'm using margins but I guess this is not the best solution and it'll change in different phones, anyway my second button doesn't appear in the app. This is the xml code I have:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#807E7B">     
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtForum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="#255094"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                >
          </TextView>

        <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnBack"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="right"
              android:text="New Thread"
              android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        </Button>

        <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnBrowser"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="right"
              android:text="Browser"
              android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I expected:

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/jheq1k.png]

Thanks

Comment: you can use relative layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/upperView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Hello.."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button 2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upperView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

you will end up with

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `RelativeLayout` and for your TextView set attribute

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

for button in the right set

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

the second one

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/your_button"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a relative layout instead, it will be easier because in a relative layout all the views are defined relative to each other, so they fit on multiple screen sizes. Read up some more on it here:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to everybody's answers, it would be tricky for performance to use [`<merge/>`](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) tag as a root tag and place inside it `RelativeLayout` with `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
       <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#807E7B"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtForum"
        android:text="YOUR_TEXT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#255094"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="2" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBrowser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnBack"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="1" >
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But keep in mind, to set Your strings into string-resources, not as hard coded text. Even keep in mind, if You use this relativeLayout, that the first Button (Your left button) has to be set after set the second button(Your right button). This only works, if the button, that should be right, still exists before setting the left button.

[image]